# Windows Terminal Server Login Failure - RST SYN

Tags: authentication, server, packet, rdp

We have terminal servers serving more than 25 users on daily basis on 2 sites. Out of no where we started to get "Connection Refused" or "Remote Desktop can't connect ..." messages on our clients. Looking into the traffic, I see our terminal servers reply SYN with another "RST SYN" packet on TCP connect. Users however can simply wait for a few seconds to a minute before they are able to start the remote session.

Looking deeper into the logs:
**TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager Debug**

- TERMSRV: ERR::IConnection->Accept failed: 0xd000020f in CListenerEx::TransferWorkItem
- TERMSRV: ERR::ptrExt->AcceptConnection failed: 0xd000020f in CConnectionEx::Accept

This issue is very similar to https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2021941-remoteapps-do-not-always-open-on-the-first-try yet we have two servers on different network/site experiencing the same issue on the same day.

Any ideas? Thanks!

-T

Comment: Stack overflow focuses on programming - you should post this question to our sister site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: Restarted another thread in ServerFault. Thx. -T